# Kotlin - Factory Function for Class with Private Constructor

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, is it possible to have a factory function that creates an instance of a class with a private constructor?

My goal is to enforce the factory function to be used and to prevent instantiation via the class's constructor.

Example:

```
// factory function, valid
val myInstance = myClassOf()

// class instantiation, invalid
val myInstance = MyClass()
```

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of some of the built-in factory functions like `intArrayOf()`, e.g.

```
// works
val myIntArray = intArrayOf()

// not possible as IntArray has a private constructor
val myIntArray = IntArray()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import MyClass.Companion.myClassOf

class MyClass private constructor() {
    companion object {
        fun myClassOf() = MyClass()
    }
}

//val myInstance1 = MyClass() // not allowed
val myInstance2 = myClassOf()
```

Comment: You don't need to if you import the companion object: `MyClass.Companion.myClassOf` - I'll update the answer to be clearer

Comment: @JKLy so I'll need to import the Companion object or the class to reference this function. Guessing that `intArrayOf()` is given special treatment and isn't replicable for my own factory function? Ideally, I would like to be able to just import the package of the class and not the class itself.

Comment: Technically `IntArray` has a public constructor - the reason why `val myIntArray = IntArray()` doesn't compile is because the constructor has the signature `IntArray(size)`. I don't believe you can call a top-level function or a function on a Companion object without qualifying it or importing it.

Comment: @Pooch also note, having to import a function is pretty much the same as doing `import static` in Java.

Comment: @Pooch You could define the function at the package level (e.g. outside any classes) if you only want to have to import the package and make the constructor `internal` instead if that suits your needs.

Comment: Importing the Companion totally takes away from the point of creating the companion object method imo. @Haim's answer of naming it appropriately is the better solution here.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) in this way:

```
class MyClass private constructor() {
  companion object {
    operator fun invoke() = MyClass()
  }
}

val myInstance = MyClass() // Calls the factory function invoke()
```

Name the factory function if it has a special meaning. For example:

```
class MyClass private constructor(values: List<String>) {
  companion object {
    fun of(vararg values: String) = MyClass(values.toList())
  }
}

val myInstance = MyClass.of("first", "second")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Builder instead.

```
class FoodOrder private constructor(
  val bread: String?,
  val condiments: String?,
  val meat: String?,
  val fish: String?) {

    data class Builder(
      var bread: String? = null,
      var condiments: String? = null,
      var meat: String? = null,
      var fish: String? = null) {

        fun bread(bread: String) = apply { this.bread = bread }
        fun condiments(condiments: String) = apply { this.condiments = condiments }
        fun meat(meat: String) = apply { this.meat = meat }
        fun fish(fish: String) = apply { this.fish = fish }
        fun build() = FoodOrder(bread, condiments, meat, fish)
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-builder-pattern